# IsolatedStorageSettings throws an IsolatedStorageFileStream when I try to get value

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, exception, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to get a boolean value I saved using isolatedStoragesettings like this:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue(KEYSTRING, out myBoolValue);
```

but I get this exception only when I debug
    Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

when I use (run without debug) Ctrl+F5 it works just fine. any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: Does this occur in the emulator and/or an actual device?

Comment: on the device itself. only in debugging

Comment: and it does work on the emulator?

Answer (score 3):

It [appears](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/232449/569636.aspx/1) that this exception can be the result of accessing `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` from multiple threads (which would include the completion handler for HTTP requests).

I assume `IsolatedStorageSettings` keeps a shared `Stream` internally so multiple readers causes it to enter an invalid state.

The solution is simply to serialize access to the settings. Any time you need access to your settings, make it happen on the UI thread (via `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`) or use a lock:

```
public static class ApplicationSettingsHelper
{
    private static object syncLock = new object();

    public static object SyncLock { get { return syncLock; } }
}

// Later

lock(ApplicationSettingsHelper.SyncLock)
{
    // Use IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings
}
```

Alternatively, you could hide the lock by using a delegate:

```
public static class ApplicationSettingsHelper
{
    private static object syncLock = new object();

    public void AccessSettingsSafely(Action<IsolatedStorageSettings> action)
    {
        lock(syncLock)
        {
            action(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings);
        }
    }
}

// Later
ApplicationSettingsHelper.AccessSettingsSafely(settings =>
{
    // Access any settings you want here
});
```

Comment: +1 your answer, but I have to wonder if this addresses the reentrancy issue of the UI thread with message pumps which often causes such concurrent accesses.