# Windows Phone Storing Key Value Pairs

Tags: c#, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I am making an application where I think the best way to store the state of the application is to have Key and Value pairs.

I am unsure whether to save this data in the FILE within isolated storage OR to save it as an App Setting as that is already set-up to be key value pairs.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple key-value pair data use the `IsolatedStorageSettings`. For complex data you should consider other means.

You could wrap the usage of `IsolatedStorageSettings` in a way that the values aren't read from the file each time, but cached when read for the first time. You might also want to make it thread-safe if you, for example, want to access the settings also from a background agent.

Comment: Hi Sami. Thansk for your feedback. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by wrapping the usage and making it thread-safe. Could you kindly show me an example or tutorial on this please?

Comment: You can check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096560/isolatedstoragesettings-throws-an-isolatedstoragefilestream-when-i-try-to-get-va

Sorry it took so long to respond.